# udp server multi process with fork in c

Tags: c, sockets, udp, multiprocessing, fork

I need to create a new process for each new "connection" from some client on my udp server made in c

I need to have multi users,
so for that I use fork.

my problem is with messages received by the server and creating a new process for each message

The code snippet illustrates, the problem is that with each new message received in the recvfrom function it creates a new process, even though it is the same one aware. I need to for each new process instantiated, that client x, send message to the same process

```
 while (1) {
        printf("\UDP Server: waiting connection...");
        bytes = recvfrom (sock, (char *)&frame_recv, sizeof(Frame), MSG_WAITALL, (sock_addr*) &client, &size_client);

        if (bytes > 0) {
            buffer[bytes] = '\0';
            printf("\nServidor UDP: message -> %s", buffer);
            pid = fork();

            if (pid < 0) {
                perror("UDP Serve: ERRO in while forking \n");
                exit(1);
            }

            if (pid == 0) {
                sendto(
                   socket,
                   (const char *)&frame_send,
                   sizeof(Frame),
                   MSG_CONFIRM,
                   (sock_addr*)&server,
                   sizeof(server)
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

So to do this I use a three Handshaking, the code snippet below is narrowing down what I'm saying. I have a first sock to "establish" the connection, the server responds with an ack and the new port with which the client will have to communicate and thus create new process and starto that client function

```
   while (true) {
        bytes = recvfrom (sock, (char *)&frame_recv, sizeof(Frame), MSG_WAITALL, (sock_addr*) &client, &size_client);
        if(bytes > 0) {
            pid = fork();

            if(pid == 0) {
                client();
            }
            if(pid < 0) {
                perro("bad Forking");
                exit(-2);
            }
        }
    }
```

In this client function I create a new socket and bind it as a new port, and so that process x is only listening to a client, I get a new while within that process listening to the messages
void client(void) {

```
bindSock(&new_server, new_sockt);

while (true) {
    printf("PID: %i\n", getpid());

    bytes = recvfrom(new_socket, (char *) &new_frane_recv, sizeof(Frame), MSG_WAITALL, (sock_addr *) &new_client, &new_size_client);

    if (bytes > 0) {
        iniciaCliente(&(new_frane_recv), new_sockt, new_client);
    }
}
```

}

my problem is that I can not get the OS to generate a random port, it always returns zero when I use getsockname.

I wonder if all this I'm doing is valid too? because I create a new process with one server for each client.

This is a college job, I have to do with udp and fork

sorry for the giant question, I'm a little lost '-'

Comment: UDP does not have the concept of a connection like TCP has. There is no need to fork for every client since all can use the same socket to read (`recvfrom`) and send (`sendto`).

Comment: There is no 1:1 relationship between a UDP socket and a peer by default. You can use a single UDP socket to send/receive messages with multiple peers. To do what you are attempting, force a 1:1 relationship by creating a new UDP socket when a new peer is detected, `connect()` that socket to the peer using the remote addr reported by `recvfrom()`, and `fork()` a process that uses `send()`/`recv()` with that socket. You may run into issues with `recvfrom()` in the main process still receiving messages that you want a forked process to receive, so you should forget using forks in UDP